# Как сделать выезжающий из блока текст? (Элемент F.A.Q.)

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Всем привет. Есть блок F.A.Q., он содержит заголовок и текст, который должен показываться по клику на заголовок. Если менять display на block-none, то текст не выплывает, ибо display - дискретное св-во. Как сделать плавное выплывание блока? 
Codepen: https://codepen.io/Alexxosipov/pen/zzgLyg

Код:

```
<div class="quest quest_active" id="quest08">
    <p class="title">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing.</p>
    <div class="text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quo blanditiis reprehenderit quasi corporis quibusdam rerum aliquid consectetur? Animi, nesciunt tempora.</div>
</div>
```

LESS:

```
.quest {            
        padding: 40px 20px;
        border: 3px dashed rgb(200,200,200);
        margin: 30px auto;
        width: 50%;
        cursor: pointer;
        transition: .3s;
        border-radius: 20px;
        max-width: 700px;
        position: relative;
        .title {
            font-size: 2rem;

            color: @contrast;
            font-weight: 700;
        }
        .text {
            position: relative;             
            transition: .3s;            
        }
        &:hover {
            border: 3px dashed @contrast;
        }
        &_active {              
            border: 3px solid white;
            box-shadow: 0px 9px 24px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.45);
            .text {
                display: block;
            }
            &:hover {
                border: 3px dashed white;
            }
        }
    }
```

jQuery:

```
$('.quest').click(function(){
    $(this).toggleClass('quest_active');
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Добавил новый класс .quest_first для того, чтобы первый вопрос был изначально открыт.

```
$('.quest').on('click',function() {
  $(this).toggleClass('quest_active').find('.text').slideToggle(500);
});
```

Рабочий пример тут - https://codepen.io/Cheg/pen/PjMMZE